# Squash on default when using git subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm often running

```
git subtree pull -P shared shared master
```

but I usually forget to put `--squash` at the end which ends up duplicating most of my git history. Is it possible to make git use that by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`git config branch.master.mergeoptions  "--squash"`

or if you want this behavior to be global to all your `git` projects:

`git config --global branch.master.mergeoptions  "--squash"`

**Edit:**

As Ingo pointed out, this solution will apply the `--squash` option to `merge` operations in general.

Comment: Doesn't this apply to all merges? Not only when using subtrees?

Comment: Yes it does. I edited my answer with your remark. I don't think there is anything specific to subtrees in `git config`, so if you want that, I think you are stuck with learning to add the option every time or use an alias. :-)